# asp.net Mention Path name within Local

Tags: asp.net

I am using Exec `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` in class file using string builder to append the from and To address.NowI need to attache the file which will be in Local solution folder (Within the solution I have Created the folder)

```
          strSql.Append("Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='SLAToolProfile',");strSql.Append("@recipients='");
        strSql.Append(eMailToaddresses);

        strSql.Append("',@file_attachments='");
        string Path = "~/Material/study material.doc";
        strSql.Append(Path);
```

when I using the above format I got file attached Error .How do I mention the path which should be in local folder within the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute method:

```
strSql.Append("Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='SLAToolProfile',");strSql.Append("@recipients='");
        strSql.Append(eMailToaddresses);

        strSql.Append("',@file_attachments='");
        string Path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Material/study material.doc");
        strSql.Append(Path);
```

that should work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160(v=vs.90).aspx

**Update**

Ok done a bit more digging, turns out that when you use sp_send_dbmail, the attachment location is the location relative to the **DB Server** not the machine running the code. So the first issue you've got is to make this file location accessible to the DB server, i.e. use a file share and a UNC location. So you can't use `~`. The Db Server has no comprehension where your route is...!

Comment: I tried this But I got Attachment file /SLAEMSite/Material/Material.doc is invalid. error

Comment: I'm not that familar with this sp, does it require a local path to the file i.e. C:\docs\file.doc or a virtual path http:\\www.test.com\file.doc? I'd imagine the earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
string filename = "study material.doc";
string storePath = Server.MapPath("~/Material");
string finalPath = Path.Combine(storePath,filename);
```

`Server.MapPath()` Converts your virtual path to absolute application Path;